# How to get an input field value in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and I would like some help getting a value from an input field:

In my form I have:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="groupId" value="1">
```

If I was using jQuery I would do:

```js
var group_id = $('#groupId').val();
```

However, in Vue I don't know how to bind the hidden field:

```html
<div id="app">
   <input type="text" v-model="groupId"> //Where do I put the value?
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        groupId: //What do I put here to get the field's value?
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12):

**Update to the update**: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46255207/392102). Previously updated answer was wrong.

Original answer:

In Vue, you don't get things from the view and put things into the view. Vue does that. You do all manipulations in the viewmodel, and make bindings in the view so that Vue knows how to synchronize it. So you'd bind the input to your model data item:

```
<input type="hidden" id="groupId" v-model="groupId">
```

and set its value in your viewmodel:

```
data: {
    groupId: 1
}
```

Comment: Ok, I think I'm all confused here. I'm learning Laravel and Vue together. So I have a vue template for a datagrid and I need to pass the value of the group id from the controller to either vue or the blade file. I'm not sure how I can pass it into the vue template. Going to dig a bit more

Comment: @SigalZahavi Slight update: your use of `v-model` was fine. Sorry if that confused anything. The main point is that the value needs to be set in the viewmodel. I don't use Laravel, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Roy, first thanks for helping. If we forget about Laravel. In your example you do groupId: 1, but where do you get this 1 from? It is a dynamic value. How do I get it?

Comment: @SigalZahavi It is dynamic from where? Can you feed it to your JavaScript, or is it only available when you're generating the HTML?

Comment: @SigalZahavi: here value of `groupId` is set initially. You can update it later like `this.groupId = 2` inside any vue method after getting value from laravel controller using ajax or axios.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question. I'm working with Vue + Laravel.

For me, the solution was simple after searching and not finding a concrete solution in the Vue documentation.

Simply:

`document.getElementById('MyId').value;`

Details in → https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

It is not the most efficient solution, but it works for now!

Greetings.

Answer (score 3):

Working sample of getting value from input field in this case it is hidden type:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test">

<script>
new Vue ({
    created () {
        const field = document.querySelector("input[name=test]").value
        console.log(field)
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: best answer from about hidden input for vue.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question using vue. This works by using vanilla javascript.

Comment: Okay so show us how to do that exactly in vue? @subharb

Answer (score 1):

this code helped me 
i hope that this work with you

1. define the input

```
        <div class="root">
            <input type="hidden" ref="groupId" value="1">
            <button type="button" v-on:click="get_id()">test</button>
        </div>
```

2. define the method

```
new Vue({
  el: ".root",
  data: {
    id: null,
  }
  methods: {
    get_id() {
      this.id = this.$refs.groupId.value;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// if you want it displayed on your page, use {{ groupId }}

/* you can get the value by using @change.enter=".." @keypress.enter="getInputValue",
   or @input="getInputValue" or @click="getInputValue" using button, 
   or if it is with a form element, @submit.prevent="getInputValue" */

/* @keypress.enter tracks input but only calls the function when the Enter key 
   is pressed, @input track changes as it's being entered */

// it is important to use event.preventDefault() when using @change or @keypress

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="groupId">
  <p> {{ groupId }} </p>

  <button @click="getInputValue">Get Input</button>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    groupId: //What do I put here to get the field's value?

    // for what to put there, you can use an empty string or null
    groupId: "",
  },

  // to get the value from input field
  methods: {
    getInputValue: function() {
      if(this.groupId !== "") {
        console.log(this.groupId);
      }
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an input value in Vue, we can use the v-model directive to set up a two-way binding between the value and a variable

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input
      type="text"
      v-model="text"
      placeholder="Text"
      @input="handleInput"
    />
    <br />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput(event) {
      console.log(event.target.value);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

look at this I did it in laravel, vuejs, vuetable2 and children's row, and don't use the v-model:

```
this.$refs['est_'+id_det].localValue
```

en VUE:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<b-form-select class="form-control selectpicker" :ref="'est_'+props.row.id_detalle_oc"
 :value="props.row.id_est_ven" v-on:change="save_estado(props.row.id_detalle_oc)">
    <option value="0">Sin estado</option>
    <option value="1">Pendiente</option>
    <option value="2">Impresa</option>
    <option value="3">Lista</option>
</b-form-select>
```

in methods

```
methods: {
        save_estado:function (id_det){
            var url= 'ordenes-compra/guardar_est_ven'
            var id_estado = this.$refs['est_'+id_det].localValue
             axios.post(url,{
                id_det: id_det,
                id_est_ven: id_estado,
                est_ven: est_ve
            }).then(function (response) {
                var respuesta= response.data;
                if(respuesta == "OK"){
                swal({
                        type: 'success',
                        title: '¡Éxito!',
                        text: 'Estado modificado',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Entendido',
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
```

I hope it helps, I've been hanging around for a while.
Regards

Answer (score -2):

Hi you can also try the following:

```
const input = this.$el.firstElementChild;
```

in case you are using TypeScript, declare input as:

```
: HTMLInputElement
```

Then, you can simply get the value if you do:

```
input.value
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -3):

Ok, this does the job: document.querySelector('#groupId').getAttribute('value');

Comment: It is about vue.js, not pure js.