# How to load default form values into vue object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here is my embedded code:

HTML:

```
<div id="user-panel">
     <div class="text-center">
       {{ fillItem }}
     </div>     

          <form method="POST" action="http://site5/user_account/experiences/17" accept-charset="UTF-8" v-on:submit.prevent="updateItem(17)">

            <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
            <!-- Employer Field -->
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <label for="employer">Employer:</label>
              <input class="form-control" v-model="fillItem.employer" name="employer" type="text" value="Some Emplyer" id="employer">
            </div>

            <!-- Designation Field -->
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <label for="designation">Designation:</label>
              <input class="form-control" v-model="fillItem.designation" name="designation" type="text"     value="some designation" id="designation">
            </div>
            <!-- Submit Field -->
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
              <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
            </div>
          </form>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<div id="user-panel">
     <div class="text-center">
       {{ fillItem }}
     </div>     

          <form method="POST" action="http://site5/user_account/experiences/17" accept-charset="UTF-8" v-on:submit.prevent="updateItem(17)">

            <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
            <!-- Employer Field -->
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <label for="employer">Employer:</label>
              <input class="form-control" v-model="fillItem.employer" name="employer" type="text" value="Some Emplyer" id="employer">
            </div>

            <!-- Designation Field -->
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
              <label for="designation">Designation:</label>
              <input class="form-control" v-model="fillItem.designation" name="designation" type="text"     value="some designation" id="designation">
            </div>
            <!-- Submit Field -->
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
              <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
            </div>
          </form>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep88/rk7bezsk/13) for that.

What I want to achieve is to load the default form field values into a vue object.

The form fields do have some default values, but vue makes them blank. How can I load the default form values in vue? I can't embed the values through direct vue object, as values are going to be dynamic, and Javascript code will be placed in a special.js file.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/deep88/rk7bezsk/13

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're trying to do but to load data into your model you can use the `created` hook and load the data with an ajax request from your server. Something like in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zkfts304/).

Comment: Why not use a placeholder if it will be static anyways. If you want to pre-populate your data you should do it in your Javascript.

Comment: hi awolf , data is already retrieved and populated in form with page load, inside value field of each input box, what is want is to make that data, initial value for that input., however, vue put it away.

Comment: Hi stephen, Why not use a placeholder if it will be static anyways. can you elaborate a little more this piece of line, on how can i do so?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676524/392102

Comment: Following [these](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) simple rules could improve your questions a lot. I suggest to follow them. I partially fixed your question now, but I can't be with you every time :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a explanation for `v-model` in the [Doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events):

`<input v-model='something'>`

is just syntactic sugar for

`<input :value='something' @input="value => { something = value }">`

So after you assign value to input, Vue would reset the value of input by something from data of Vue instance like above. That means you couldn't pass default form field value into Vue object by `value` attribute of input tag.

For initialization, you can try to directly set Vue object when you init Vue instance, or modify Vue object in Callback function of dynamic access to default values.

Hope for you a little help.