# Vue form input bindings with existing value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to bind an input with a model. When the page loads, the input has a value. But when I bind with a model, it gets empty as I initialize the model with a null or empty value.

```
<div id="update-email">
  <input type="text" name="email" value="me@example.com" v-model="email">
  {{ email }}
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#update-email',
  data() {
    return {
      email: '',
    };
  }
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Debiprasad/v8wyj2kw/

How can I update `email` value with the value of the input when it loads?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3924 and https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vue-2-and-initial-input-form-values

Answer (score 5):

I handle this by initializing my model value to the value of the input field.  This way when the vue initially sets the input field the model value, it's the value that was in the input field.

Example below using jquery:

```
 <div id="update-email">
   <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="me@example.com" v-model="email">
    {{ email }}
 </div>
```

Javasacript:

```
new Vue({
el: '#update-email',
   data() {
     return {
       email: $('#email').val(),
     };
   }
 });
```

If you want to do it without jquery, just change `$('#email').val()` to `document.getElementById('email').value`

Comment: +1 Best answer AFAIK at the time of writing.  @Debiprasad please consider marking as accepted to get it bumped to the top.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a directive to put the value into the element and issue an input event.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#update-email',
  data: {
    email: null
  },
  directives: {
    init: {
      bind(el) {
        el.value = el.getAttribute('value');
        el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="update-email">
  <input v-init type="text" name="email" value="me@example.com" v-model="email"> {{ email }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a non-JQuery variant of Ron C's answer, and to make explicit the answer suggested by the link yuriy linked to, here's [the solution suggested by the creator of Vue.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3924#issuecomment-253351024):

https://jsfiddle.net/vzns7us7/

**Template:**

```
<script>
// rendered by server
window.__FORM__ = {
  fill: 'my_default_value'
}
</script>

<div id="test">
  <input type="text" v-model="fill">
  {{ fill }}
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#test',
    data () {
        return window.__FORM__ || {
          fill: 'none'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ron's response and yuriy636's comment are perfectly answering your question. Only to complement with a more advanced solution using Vuex (https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/):

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    email: 'me@example.com'
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#update-email',
  store,
  created() {
    this.email = this.$store.state.email
  },
  data() {
    return {
      email: '',
    };
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.4.0/vuex.min.js"></script>

<div id="update-email">
  <input type="text" name="email" v-model="email"> {{ email }}
</div>
```